# icon not displayed on ribbon, the new primefaces 5.1 component

Tags: primefaces, icons, ribbon

When using the following code :

```
<p:commandButton value="New" icon="ui-ribbonicon-new" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton" type="button"/>
```

The icon ui-ribbonicon-new is not displayed!

I am using Primefaces 5.1 with jsf 2.1 on glassfish 3.1.
Can someone help about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add style into your page like below css.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-ribbon .ui-colorpicker .ui-button {
        height: 24px;
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-new {
        margin-left: -10px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/new.png']}");
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-save {
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/save.png']}");
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-paste {
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/paste.png']}");
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-cut {
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/cut.png']}");
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-print {
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/print.png']}");
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-zoomin {
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/zoomin.png']}");
    }

    .ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-zoomout {
        background-image: url("#{resource['demo/images/icon/zoomout.png']}");
    }
</style>
```

You can download all of pictures from [primefaces repository](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/showcase/tags/5_1/src/main/webapp/resources/demo/images/icon/).

Comment: Many thanks Wittakarn, it worked like a charm from the first shot.
But I still have one question: why doesn’t it work out of the box like for the icons we use in buttons for instance: icon=”ui-icon-plus”?

Comment: @Hicham Primefaces use jQuery UI Based, and jQuery UI provides icons(http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/) such as ui-icon-plus, ui-icon-newwin and etc. If you see that link, it did not have icons  which show in the ribbon.